# How do I create a scroll bar containing pics that links to specific time codes in 2 Videos to play simultaneously?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I've got a project. Its essentially a recording of a Seminar.

There are 5 speakers + 1 Opening. Each of the 6 clips involves 1 Video with Sound, One video of the Screen and a PPT. I am able to convert the PPT into jpg. Now I need to have, on one screen. The Slide video (silent) playing in the main area, the Speaker Video (with sound) playing in the top right hand corner, and a Scroll bar containing thumbnails of the PPT slides below the Slide Video.

My audience needs to be be able to scroll through the bar to find the slide they want, AS THE VIDEO IS PLAYING, and when they click the PPT JPG, Both vids will go to that specific time code where the slide was used and continue playing from there.

Terms of Reference would be a) Speaker 1.flv, b) Screen 1.flv  and c) PPT 1 - Slide 1-100.

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript 2, you can use seek() to jump to a specific time.

```
my_FLVplybk.seek(time:Number)
```

More documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002450.html